# Theme not showing up

Tags: theme-development, themes

I'm creating a custom theme on a local install on WordPress on Ubuntu. The theme is a separate directory within `/themes/` and has both `index.html` and `style.css`. It works on other installs. I have made myself the owner and increased the permissions to no avail. Any other ideas?

Comment: I was struggling with this last night and came across your post. It was inexplicable. Nothing worked. In the end, I had forgotten that I had set up a Multisite. And on multisite, you have to manually enable any themes you want available to the network (or a specific site) in the Network Admin area. Just in case this could help somebody else...

Answer (score 2):

Please learn [how to template for WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates) first, before proceeding further. It will help you understand how you are proceeding and what you are achieving.

Please note what is the Minimal requirement for a theme to BE a 'theme':

- **`index.php`** (not `index.html`)
- **`style.css`**

That's it.

It will work *like* a complete theme, and you can activate the theme without any harassment.

But to make it a complete theme you have work a lot, and you have to start from the `style.css` and `functions.php`... all are explained here in Codex:

- [**WordPress Theme Development** - Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

Comment: I understand all of that. Forgive me the index.html was a typo. I meant index.php.

As I mentioned the basic theme I am using works on other Wordpress installs but not mine. Here's a link: https://github.com/rsteggy/Simple-Blog

Again it's in the themes folder, I've changed permissions, and made myself an owner which were the only other troubleshooting steps I found for this issue.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>` in `header.php` is a wrong declaration. It should be on the next line `<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>`.

Comment: I updated that in my header.php but the theme is still not showing up on my local install

Comment: I follow a basic debug rules I made: I simply cut `ctrl+x` a portion of the code, from the main template files (`functions.php`, `index.php`, `header.php`, `footer.php` etc.) and save `ctrl+s` the file and then reload the front-end. If that portion is causing the problem and everything else is okay, the page will load, and I can then concentrate on that particular portion of the code.